The difference between .C and .c file extension
I am writing a program that can play tic-tac-toe. I got too excited and didn't see that I made my program with capital .C extension. My program works perfectly in this situation. But when I do it in a .c extension. The compiler shows errors.
My O.S is Linux Mint. My compiler is gcc 11.2.0.
What is happening here?
This doesn't work on .c but it works in .C
#include <stdio.h>

struct cell {
    int x;
    int y;
    char data;
};


struct cell a1={1,1}, b1= {1,2}, c1={1,3},
            a2={2,1}, b2= {2,2}, c2={2,3},
            a3={3,1}, b3= {3,2}, c3={3,3};
            
struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};

int main(){
}

This are the error messages:
gcc -Wall -o  "function_tsting" "function_tsting.c" -lm (in directory: /home/stup)
function_tsting.c:13:24: error: initializer element is not constant

   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                        ^~
function_tsting.c:13:24: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[0]’)
function_tsting.c:13:27: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                           ^~
function_tsting.c:13:27: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[1]’)
function_tsting.c:13:30: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                              ^~
function_tsting.c:13:30: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[2]’)
function_tsting.c:13:33: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                                 ^~
function_tsting.c:13:33: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[3]’)
function_tsting.c:13:36: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                                    ^~
function_tsting.c:13:36: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[4]’)
function_tsting.c:13:39: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                                       ^~
function_tsting.c:13:39: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[5]’)
function_tsting.c:13:42: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                                          ^~
function_tsting.c:13:42: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[6]’)
function_tsting.c:13:45: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                                             ^~
function_tsting.c:13:45: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[7]’)
function_tsting.c:13:48: error: initializer element is not constant
   13 | struct cell matrix[9]={a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3};
      |                                                ^~
function_tsting.c:13:48: note: (near initialization for ‘matrix[8]’)
Compilation failed.


On OSes that differentiate between lowercase and uppercase in filenames(*), such as Linux, the .C extension is often interpreted (by the compiler, or at least the GNU compilers) as a C++ source file. The lowercase .cextension is interpreted as a C source file.
Your somefile.C file is thus interpreted as a C++ file, and compiled as such, even by the gcc compiler (that is, not by the g++ compiler). The somefile.c is compiled as a C file.
The code you have is correct in C++. It is not correct in C. See the error messages as to what is not correct.
I recommend to always specify a standard to the compiler, with the -std option, such as -std=c11. That clarifies how the code should be interpreted, and even what version.

As for an explanation of the error message, see this question and answer (which is marked as a duplicate, but I find the answer here a bit clearer).

(*) personal gripe: macOS is horrible in this regard: it can show a file as somefile.C, and the compiler will interpret it as a C++ source file, but ls somefile.c or worse, rm somefile.c, will list or remove somefile.C. In fact, you can't have both somefile.c and somefile.C; they are the same file, but spelt differently on macOS (apparently, it's called case-preserving, but in effect it's case-insensitive). This odd behaviour has caused errors.

Interesting. I wasn't aware of c vs C distinction. That's a weird design choice if you ask me.  However I was about .s vs .S one (the former is assembled as is, the latter is first preprocessed by cpp).

That clarifies how the code should be interpreted So, -x option is used for that, like -xc or -xc++, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-14.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html

Case-sensitivity and case-insensitivity is a feature of the file system, not of macOS. If you do not like it, you can use a different volume type.

A simpler way of avoiding problems is to use one of the alternative C++ file extensions: all of .cc, .cpp and .cxx are usually recognized as extensions for C++ files (see the GCC documentation on Compiling C++ programs).  These are safe for use on case-insensitive file systems.

@JonathanLeffler .cpp is such a common standard that using anything else when deliberately writing C++ code would be very fishy practice.
